When is a linear isomorphism of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ given by unitary conjugation?
Let $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ represent the space of $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$. We will think of it as a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space.
Notice that if $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is invertible, then the map $f_A: M_n(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow M_n(\mathbb{C})$, given by $B \mapsto ABA^{-1}$ is a linear isomorphism.
I have the converse question: suppose we are given a linear isomorphism $f: M_n(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow M_n(\mathbb{C})$. When is $f$ given by a matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $f(B) = A B A^{-1}$ for all $B \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$? Is there a simple condition to detect this? What if we additionally require $A$ to be a unitary matrix?

To be clear: by "isomorphism" do you mean that you want the algebra structure (i.e., matrix multiplication) to be preserved by $f$? If so, the Skolem-Noether theorem linked by LSpice is the complete answer. However, if you really mean "we think of it as a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space" completely literally and just want $f$ to be an isomorphism in the linear algebra sense (i.e., preserves vector space operations, but not matrix multiplication) then I can perhaps give a more useful answer.

@NathanielJohnston I had meant the weaker meaning only (isomorphism as vector spaces), and I'm interested to know if it leads to a different answer than the one by LSpice.

The Skolem–Noether theorem says that $f$ arises by conjugation by an element of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb C)$ if and only if it also preserves matrix multiplication.

To add to this: the matrix "$A$" can be chosen to be unitary if and only if $f$ is a $$-automorphism (i.e., if and only if $f(X^) = f(X)^*$ for all $X$).

As an alternative to LSpice's great answer:
Every linear map $f$ acting on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ has a Choi matrix defined by
$$
C_f := \sum_{i,j}E_{i,j}\otimes f(E_{i,j}) \in M_n(\mathbb{C}) \otimes M_n(\mathbb{C}),
$$
where $E_{i,j}$ is the matrix whose entries all equal $0$, except for a single $1$ in the $(i,j)$-entry, and it is a standard fact that $r := \mathrm{rank}(C_{f})$ is the smallest number of terms needed in a formula of the form
$$
f(X) = \sum_{i=1}^rA_iXB_i.
$$
Furthermore, if $r = 1$ then it's not too hard to show that $B_1 = A_1^{-1}$ if and only if $f(I) = I$. We thus get the following:
Theorem: Suppose $f : M_n(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a linear isomorphism. Then there exists an invertible matrix $A$ so that $f(X) = AXA^{-1}$ for all $X$ if and only if $f(I) = I$ and $\mathrm{rank}(C_{f}) = 1$.
If you want to require additionally that $A$ can be chosen to be unitary, then add the extra condition "and $C_f$ is positive semidefinite" to the above theorem (this follows from the theory of completely positive linear maps, which are described a bit in the above Wikipedia link).

Shouldn't $C_f$ lie in $\mathbb C^{n\times n} \otimes \mathbb C^{n\times n}$?

@LSpice - fixed, thanks.
